# ShinyTree with default selected value

Tags: shiny, default-value, shinytree

I'm trying to implement a shinyTree that has a default selected value. Does anybody know if that is possibly?

I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyTree/shinyTree.pdf) or the examples that came with [the package](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree).

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: did you look at the examples given in https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree?

Answer (score 2):

Set the 'stselected' attribute of your desired nodes to TRUE

Example:

```
output$tree <- renderTree({
   sss=list('Nodes' = list('Node1' = '1', 'Node2' = '2'))
   attr(sss[[1]][['Node1']],"stselected")=TRUE # <---
   attr(sss[[1]],"stopened")=TRUE
   sss
})
```